# Adding a Chrome /Metal filter to an image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, imagefilter

I have an image being displayed on a webpage, I need that image to have a chrome effect. Whenever I Google anything with the word "Chrome", it just brings up results linked to Google Chrome browser - which is not what I am after

It is used for a car dealerships website to make the first featured image stand out.

This is what they already use (which they manually add the Chrome effect to on Paintshop Pro), I would like the website to use this effect using CSS (or another language if easier)

ORIGINAL IMAGE: https://f7432d8eadcf865aa9d9-9c672a3a4ecaaacdf2fee3b3e6fd2716.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/C642/U1793/IMG_7200-large.jpg

CHROMED IMAGE: https://f7432d8eadcf865aa9d9-9c672a3a4ecaaacdf2fee3b3e6fd2716.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/C642/U1793/IMG_7117-large.jpg

If anyone has any Advanced CSS to add this Chrome filter to the image, to make it like the above as possible, that would be great

Comment: And what did you try yourself? Where is your starting point in code?

Comment: I have used the CSS "Filters", but that doesn't give me the results I am after

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_effects.asp
visit here maybe it will help you to create what you want.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, as a runnable snippet, and describe what is wrong with it. It makes it very much easier for us to help is there is some code to base an answer on. For your problem you will have to include a suitable image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <img src="https://f7432d8eadcf865aa9d9-9c672a3a4ecaaacdf2fee3b3e6fd2716.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/C642/U1793/IMG_7200-large.jpg" style="???">

Comment: It is just an image tag which I want to be displayed with a Chrome effect. I am requesting some CSS which can turn the image from the original, into the Chromed version - See the original question, you can see the effect I am after. I don't have any code yet as I don't know how to do it. Standard image effects do not work

Comment: Forget the logo in the corner and the red corner banners, I just want to turn... https://f7432d8eadcf865aa9d9-9c672a3a4ecaaacdf2fee3b3e6fd2716.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/C642/U1793/IMG_7200-large.jpg INTO https://f7432d8eadcf865aa9d9-9c672a3a4ecaaacdf2fee3b3e6fd2716.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/C642/U1793/IMG_7117-large.jpg

Comment: The Chromed image in the second link, this has been made via a photo editing software (Printshop Pro) by my client. They manually chrome the image on the software then upload the Chromed version to the website. How can I make it so I can turn the first image they use into a Chrome design/ effect. I just want purely CSS. I have the HTML to display the image normally